# Creating a HTML table with Marionette views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to output a table to the DOM with Backbone and Marionette Composite views, Collection views and Item views. My code is:

```
    var TableDataView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
                tagName: "td",
                template: "#data-cell-template",

                initialize: function(){

                        console.log('IN TABLEDATA');
                        console.log('and this.model is ');
                        console.log(this.model);
                } 
    });

    var ScoreRowView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

                tagName: "tr",
                childView: TableDataView,
                template: "#row-template",

                initialize: function(){

                    console.log('in composite row and this.model is ');
                    console.log(this.model);

                    //var tableDataView = TableDataView();
                },
    });

    // The grid view
    var TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

                tagName: "table",

                template: "#table-template",

                childView: ScoreRowView,

                initialize: function () {
                    console.log('this.collection is');
                    console.log(this.collection);

                },
    });



    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Below this line is normal stuff... models, templates, data, etc.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    var countryData = [
        {
            country: "england",
            scores: [14, 56, 88]
        },
        {
            username: "ireland",
            scores: [56, 23, 90]
        }
    ];


    var Country = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var CountryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Country
    });

    var countryList = new CountryCollection(countryData);

    var tableView = new TableView({
        collection: countryList
    });

    tableView.render();
    console.log(tableView.el);
    $("#table").html(tableView.el);
```

The table should look like this:

[image]

Note the cells with the numbers have a lot of custom css and will have click events so these will need to be in their own views.

However, with the above code, the `CompositeView` is not sending the model to the `ItemView`. In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ps356f17/1/) fiddle, it does reach the `ItemView` simply by proving the `ItemView` as a `childView`. My jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vuhv7a5x/2/). How do I pass data to the `ItemView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to ScoreRowView constructor:

```
var tdData = [this.model.get('country')].concat(this.model.get('scores')).map(function(item) {
                return {
                    value: item
                }
             })
this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(tdData);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sergeir82/t53t5x78/